# threshold values in a matrix matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I need a fast way to perform threshold on image (matrix) regions.
The input is a matrix (image), threshold value and radius,
for each pixel I need to check if all values within the given radius are less than the threshold,if so, I need to save this value's (pixel's) coordinates. 
I don't want to make it with double loops, because I need to perform this task many times with several radii. 
I don't care about minimas or maximas, just that all values around a pixel will be lower than some threshold.
Any idea will be very appreciated !

Comment: You can perform a dilation with a circular structuring element, followed by a trivial thresholding in the resulting image. Since the question is tagged `matlab` I guess you are not interested in making the dilation faster, just expecting that `matlab` gives one fast enough. If you were interested on that, then there is a decent amount of work regarding decomposability and related ways to improve th efficiency of morphological operations.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know any fast algorithm for a circular neighborhood. However, if you have have rectangular neighborhood, you can implement the the check very fast look at here for more details:
http://leetcode.com/2011/01/sliding-window-maximum.html

Also, you can imporve you speed when you when you have multiple values for the radius. Simply start with the smallest value and calculate the result. For future radius values, if a point did not pass from one of the previous steps, do not process it, there exist a point in a smaller radius (so in the current radius) which is larger than the threshold.

Comment: Hi, I wasn't clear about the threshold, it can change with the radius, so, I can't spare the test for pixel who didn't "pass" from previous level. I thought on creating a mask of the size of the image, with ones only at the current window (I can create a circle in a square window, like in here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/24609, and just check if the sum of image.*mask is less than threshold.*mask. I just don't know how to avoid a loop in this case.

Comment: Thus, you simply need to define a circular filter and then use conv2 or filter2 to run calculate the sum (Matlab internally used FFT so it's way faster than nested loop implementation).

Comment: Hi, thanks, that's what I'll do, edit your answer (with the comment) and I will accept it.